# Unable to Unpublish App

Tags: android, google-play, android-developer-api, developer-console

I am getting the following error when i try to unpublish my app from play store:

**Your app has an apk with version code 1427982169 that requests the following permission(s): android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE. Apps using these permissions in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set.**

Issue: App can only be published/unpublished if the form has no errors. The app has error as i have no privacy policy for the app which was something google play did not inform me while uploading the app few years ago. I am unable to submit privacy policy and also unable to remove my app as the form error wont go until i submit privacy policy. I just want to remove my app. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

[This is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9fhL.jpg)

Comment: There are many free Privacy Policy Generator online. Search for them. make your privacy policy and place it on your server and give google the link. once they are satisfied. Unpublish your App

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

To add your privacy policy, uncheck *Not submitting a privacy policy URL at this time*, then add your privacy policy link. Finally, unpublish the app.

If you need more help, I think it's a good idea to contact Google play developer support